# Docker Node.js Module not found

Tags: node.js, docker, express, modulenotfounderror

I get a "Module Not Found" error but i am installing my npm modules i need

- express
- request
  idk why i get the error

the docker file:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8001
CMD [ "node","index.js" ]
```

The package.json

```
{
  "name": "edekaapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```

Thats my error i get:

```
Node.js v20.2.0
2023-06-05 12:32:18 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073
2023-06-05 12:32:18   throw err;
2023-06-05 12:32:18   ^
2023-06-05 12:32:18 
2023-06-05 12:32:18 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/routes/offers.js'
2023-06-05 12:32:18 Require stack:
2023-06-05 12:32:18 - /usr/src/app/index.js
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1070:15)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:27)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/index.js:6:22)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
2023-06-05 12:32:18     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
2023-06-05 12:32:18   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-06-05 12:32:18   requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/index.js' ]
2023-06-05 12:32:18 }
2023-06-05 12:32:18 
2023-06-05 12:32:18 Node.js v20.2.0
```

i build the image with this command

```
docker build -t edeka3 .
```

i tried many soulutions from stackoverflow but still got the error

Comment: Please provide the exact error messages you are encountering so that we can better understand the issue. Without the specific error messages (as `Module Not Found` this means a module is missing, but don't know which module), it is difficult to determine the exact cause of the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: i updated the post the error message is there now ^^

Comment: How are you building and running the container?  Does that error come from the image build or the container startup?  Is any of your image content actually being used, or are you replacing all of it with mounts as part of the container configuration?

Comment: i put the command in the post now if there is any more information you need tell me

Comment: `Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/routes/offers.js'`, the container system unable to find  `offers.js` file. Looks like these files are not copied into the container system when building the image. What is your code directory structure?

Comment: i can  see in the file tab in the docker desktop app that the files are copied

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
FROM node:18-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8001
CMD [ "node","index.js" ]
```

Comment: What is different from the Dockerfile in the question?  Why does it help?

Comment: i stll get the error

Comment: the difference is that this file is only looking at the package.json and not the package-lock.json